# How to define a constant `bytes32` in Solidity v0.8 and above?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, bytes32, constant

I want to define a constant `bytes32` like this:

```
bytes32 internal constant FOO = bytes32(0x01);
```

But I'm getting the following error when compiling the code above:

> Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const 1" to "bytes32".

How can I do this in Solidity v0.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to cast the constant values to `uint256`, like this:

```
bytes32 internal constant FOO = bytes32(uint256(0x01));
```

Note that you can also optionally ditch the hexadecimal prefix:

```
bytes32 internal constant FOO = bytes32(uint256(1));
```

Though you may want to keep it so that you remember that the value is a `bytes32`.